# Xamarin SyncFusion, Cropped Image not passed properly?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, crop, syncfusion

My goal is to have the **cropped** image that is edited in my CropPage.xaml (which holds the SfImageEditor to do this) passed to another class.

Here is the code to the CropPage.xaml file:

```
<SyncFusion:SfImageEditor x:Name="imgEditor"
                         ImageSaved="imgEditor_ImageSaved">
</SyncFusion:SfImageEditor>
```

Now I've edited the default toolbar at the top of the SfImageEditor page to have "Continue" as clickable, and all of this is in CropPage.xaml.cs. There's a lot more code of course but this is the main portion I believe matters:

```
// Assign function when a selection occurs.
imgEditor.ToolbarSettings.ToolbarItemSelected += ToolbarSettings_ToolbarItemSelected;

private void ToolbarSettings_ToolbarItemSelected(object sender, ToolbarItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    // When the user is ready to move on, they press continue to move to the next page. Check specifically for that.
    if(e.ToolbarItem.Text == "Continue")
    {
        // Get the image and transfer it to the next page here. (Is it really just the source?)
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ProcessPage(imgEditor.Source));
    }
}
```

Then of course, ProcessPage is just another class and its constructor RECEIVES the ImageSource. The important code is:

```
    // CropPage will pass on the image source when the user is done cropping, and image will be used for the algorithm.
    ImageSource m_savedImgSrc;

    public ProcessPage(ImageSource imgSource)
    {
        // Get rid of the navigation bar.
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        InitializeComponent();

        // Place image on screen.
        imgSpace.Source = imgSource;
    }
```

The "imgSpace" from above is just a small area to show the would be cropped image and that code in the xaml file looks like:

```
 <Image x:Name="imgSpace"
       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.65"
       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
 </Image>
```

So the plan was simple, I crop an image with the SfImageEditor inside the CropPage, and pass it to ProcessPage to display. But no matter how I crop it, it goes to ProcessPage and there is the ORIGINAL image.

I guess I did assume that when I crop the image in CropPage that the new image displayed was in the source so passing source along as you seen would solve my problem. But unfortunately that wasn't true.

There's gotta be something I'm missing to explain why I'm not getting the cropped image I'd like. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: are you saving first?  I would save and then pass the path, not the original ImageSource

Comment: If you mean by saving the image to the phone itself, I'm not doing that at all. I figured there's no need to take up extra memory space on the users phone but since the image is clearly on screen then that would be enough.

Comment: I think you need to save it.  You can delete the file when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked your requirement and shared code, and you can’t get the edited image from ImageEditor.Source property as it contains only the original ImageSource that was added in the image editor.

However, you can get the edited image stream from the image editor’s ImageSaving  event as per in the below code snippet

```
<imageeditor:SfImageEditor Source="{Binding Image}"  x:Name="editor" ImageSaving="imgEditor_ImageSaving"/>
```

Once done editing, click the `Continue` toolbar button and pass the edited image source.

```
private void ToolbarSettings_ToolbarItemSelected(object sender, ToolbarItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ToolbarItem.Text == "Continue")
        {
         // Call editor save method.
            editor.Save();
        }
    }


    private void imgEditor_ImageSaving(object sender, ImageSavingEventArgs args)
    {
       // Below line will stop the image saving to your machine. If you like to save the image in your machine, you can remove the below line.
        args.Cancel = true;

       //args.Stream contain edited image stream
        var stream = args.Stream;

       //Convert the edited stream to ImageSource
        var source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
       // Pass edited image source to the next page
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ProcessPage(source));
    }
```